# AWS ECS find out hosted/parent Task or TaskDefinition of a container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-sdk

I have AWS container running in ECS. Is there a way we can get the host Task or TaskDefinition info from container code? My container is dotnet core API.
So, I am looking for a way to read the hosted/parent task/taskdefinition from my dotnet C# code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the AWS CLI together with the ECS CLI (make sure you have both installed). 
You can list all tasks for your cluster like this:

`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster your-cluster-name`

It will return something like this:

```
{
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:5xxx:task/1133xxxxxxc"
    ]
}
```

Then you can use the returned ARN to describe multiple tasks like this:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:5xxx:task/1133xxxxxxc --cluster your-cluster-name
```